# How to filter map markers from API + Showing user's location. the code and result can be seen here https://playcode.io/846545

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
class pp
{
    static main(args)
    {           
        var KeyboardInput = 
            window.prompt("Please state which governorate you're visiting: ");
        var answer = KeyboardInput;
        const Giza = "in Giza are: The Black Pyramid, Red Pyramid, White Pyramid, Giza Pyramids, Great Sphinx of Giza, Khufu Ship, Grand Egyptian Museum, Pharaonic Village";
        const Ciaro = "in Ciaro are: Mosque of Muhammad Ali, Prince Taaz Palace, Champlion Palace, Baron Empain Palace, Sakakini Pasha Palace, Aisha Fahmy Palace, The Egyptian Museum";
        const ElAlamein = "in El-Alamein are: El Alamein World War II Military Museum";
        const Alexandira = "in Alexandira are: Alexandria National Museum, Montaza Palace, Princess Aziza Fahmy's Palace, Elharamlik Palace, King Farouk Palace, Citadel of Qaitbay";

        const AbuSimbel = "in Abu Simbel are: Abu Simbel Temples, Temple of Nefertari";
        const Aswan = "in Aswan are: Aswan Sculpture Museum, Nubian Village, Nubian Museum, Unfinished Obelisk, Temple of Kom Ombo, The Temple of Horus at Edfu, Philae Temple";
        const Luxor = "in Luxor are: Tomb of Tut Ankh Amun, Toth Tempel, Karnak Temple, Mummification Museum, Luxor Temple, Colossi of Memnon, Valley of the Queens, Valley of the Kings";
        const Elminia = "in El-Minia are: Great Aten Temple, Tomb of Panehsy, Southern Tomb 23";
        const ElFauom = "in El-Fauom are: Pyramid of Amenemhat III at Hawara, Pyramid of Senusret II";

        if ("giza" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + Giza);
        }
        else if ("ciaro" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + Ciaro);
        }
        else if ("el alamein" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + ElAlamein);
        }
        else if ("alexandira" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + Alexandira);
        }
        else if ("abu simbel" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + AbuSimbel);
        }
        else if ("aswan" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + Aswan);
        }
        else if ("luxor" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + Luxor);
        }
        else if ("elminia" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + Elminia);
        }
        else if ("el fauom" == answer)
        {
            console.log("the places available for you " + ElFauom);
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("please try agian");
            console.log("please try agian");
        }
    }
}

pp.main([]);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
      
h1 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #8AB4F8;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Egypt</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Welcome to Egypt</h1>
   <div id="map"></div>

     <script type="text/javascript">

       var locations = [
        ['Giza Pyramids', 29.97948232434399, 31.13425301801566],
        ['El Alamein World War II Military Museum', 30.841622361284365, 28.942923541443122],
        ['Champlion Palace', 30.05035902974509, 31.237959154921274],
        ['The Egyptian Museum', 30.04834162437527, 31.233411987098524],
        ['Grand Egyptian Museum', 29.99481553472096, 31.119651272926717],
        ['Montaza Palace', 31.28887128778053, 30.015786807084538],
        ['Valley of the Kings', 25.751063804476253, 32.59955291328364],
        ['Unfinished Obelisk', 24.080759744191578, 32.89685424856642],
        ['Philae Temple', 24.029915753103047, 32.884320301875256],
        ['Luxor Temple', 25.699978313521797, 32.63889733826223], 
        ['Abu Simbel Temples', 22.337489903165466, 31.625798997110277],
        ['The Temple of Horus at Edfu', 24.977505782872168, 32.87334994622213],
        ['Pyramid of Senusret II', 29.236481100096093, 30.970561095389794],
        ['Salah El Din Citadel', 29.49293131617498, 34.85132086481411]
      ];
    
       var map;
       function initMap() {
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
           center: {lat: 26.73233425107208, lng: 29.793093377254394},
           zoom: 6,
           mapId: '36dc22a636a7b743'
         });
        
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         var marker, i;
    
         for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                locations[i][1], locations[i][2]
             ),
           map: map
       });
      
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
            (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i)
       );
     }
     
    }
      function getLocation() {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {initMap({lng: position.coords.longitude, lat: position.coords.latitude});
        
          });
        } } 
        function getDistance(source, destination) {
  return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
    new google.maps.LatLng(source.lat, source.lng),
    new google.maps.LatLng(destination.lat, destination.lng)
  );
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNArtKDQXpWzHARJBw9BjDmYyawLoF3s4&callback=getLocation"
    async ></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm written a html, CSS, and JavaScript code.

I started writing the code and I have a map showing up with multiple markers but I want to have a set of marker appear only when a statement is true, and another set when another statement is true and so on.
also I'd like for it do show the user's location and show them the how close they are from the closest marker.

thanks in advance, Sarah

Comment: Do you have any code? I'm not quite sure what you are describing in your question

Comment: Using different conditions to display different markers is very common. How you approach it depends on the particulars of your use case which we know nothing about

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: What API are you using, how are the maps displayed on your website?

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example, and keep to one single question